# Raphael's `getFont` method doesn't work (?)

Tags: javascript, svg, raphael

I'm having some problems creating text using *Raphael.js*'s `print` method. To be more precise, the `getFont` method that the `print` method requires, returns an `undefined` value. I put together a very simple fiddle [**here**](http://jsfiddle.net/WbL26/) to try to find the source of the problem, but with no luck so far. The same fiddle code is bellow:

```
<div id="canvas" style="width:500px; height:300px; outline: 1px solid #000;"></div>​
```

And the JavaScript:

```
var canvas, font, text;

canvas = new Raphael(document.getElementById("canvas", 500, 300));
font = canvas.getFont("Arial");
text = canvas.print(0, 0, "Some text", font, 24).attr({ "fill": "#C00" });​
```

The canvas is created, even the path is drawn (despite the fact the the value of *font* is undefined), but the font object is returned undefined. And I've tried with "Arial" font too. After all, these two are standard, so we're not talking about custom fonts.

Any ideas why this happens?

Comment: You are aware that getFont expects cufon fonts? See: 
 stackoverflow.com/questions/4402329/can-i-use-print-in-raphael-without-cufon

Comment: I wasn't, no. Pretty new to SVG's and Raphael.js too :)

Comment: Please write an answer so I can approve it.

Comment: I will as soon as I'm not on my mobile anymore. Did you get the cufon working?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Raphael's `print` method requires you to use Cufon-font-files. From the docs on `getFont`:

> Finds font object in the registered fonts by given parameters.

and reading further at `registerFont`:

> Adds given font to the registered set of fonts for Raphaël. Should be
>   used as an internal call from within Cufón’s font file.

A little twisted.....

So if you want/need to use the `print` method you'll have to convert and supply the font files in the correct format, read about cufon **[here](http://cufon.shoqolate.com/generate/)**.

If you want to use system fonts (or *webfonts*) you can use the **[`Paper.text()`](http://raphaeljs.com/reference.html#Paper.text)** method that is pretty easy to use and you can style your text with CSS and the likes.